# Change css value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, box-shadow

I want change `box-shadow` sitting with range value like this code:

```js
function cssV(){
   var x1 = document.getElementById("range1").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("range2").value;
    var x3 = document.getElementById("range3").value;
    var x4 = document.getElementById("range4").value;
 var dic = document.getElementById("test").style;
 /* dic.boxShadow=x1+"px" x2+"px" x3+"px" x4+"px" green;*/
  
  }
```

```css
#test{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
    
     background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 10px green;
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range1" step="1" value="50" min="0" max="100" oninput="cssV(this.value)" style="width:100%;" id="range1"/>
<input type="range" name="range2" step="1" value="50" min="0" max="100" oninput="cssV(this.value)" style="width:100%;" id="range2"/>
<input type="range" name="range3" step="1" value="50" min="0" max="100" oninput="cssV(this.value)" style="width:100%;" id="range3"/>
<input type="range" name="range4" step="1" value="50" min="0" max="100" oninput="cssV(this.value)" style="width:100%;" id="range4"/>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like ok to me, see the link here. http://jsbin.com/goniqipeku/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This means I have a error in only in `+` thank you so much @hiEven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Box shadow using css property of jquery as below.
Make sure you add jquery in your code.

```
function cssV(){
   var x1 = document.getElementById("range1").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("range2").value;
    var x3 = document.getElementById("range3").value;
    var x4 = document.getElementById("range4").value;
    $("#test).css('box-shadow' , "inset " + x1 +"px " + x2+"px "+ x3+"px "+ x4+"px " + "green");

  }
```

Comment: thank so mauch i have error only in `+` ..please give me vote for my question

Answer (score 0):

Check out this working [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/T7uRh3niD8zwR9Qb2NrG?p=preview)

```
dic.boxShadow = x1 + "px " + x2 + "px " + x3 + "px " + x4 + "px " + "green";
```

Comment: thank so mauch i have error only in + ..please give me vote for my question